# How to setup a proper Eclipse Project structure?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am just starting a new semester and am currently preparing my Eclipse workspace.

I have some small projects on my own, so I thought I'd make a separation and apply some abstraction and keep a separate place for each subject and lecture, but something feels wrong.

Currently it looks something like this (and sorry if my horrid ASCII burns your eyes):

```
MySchoolName                  [JAVA PROJECT]
|-- src                       [SOURCE FOLDER]
|   |-- subject_one           [PACKAGE]
|   |   |-- lecture1          [PACKAGE]
|   |   |   |-- Foo.java
|   |   |   `-- Bar.java
|   |   `-- lecture2          [PACKAGE]
|   |-- subject_two           [PACKAGE]
|       |-- lecture1          [PACKAGE]
|       |   `-- Giraffes.java
|       `-- lecture2          [PACKAGE]
|
| etc etc..
```

**1:** Should the `subject` and `lecture` folders all be inside the `src` folder, or should each `subject`-package have its own `src`-folder?

**2:** Should the `subject` and `lecure` packages actually BE packages? Or folders, source-folders, etc. What would a decent structure look like?

Comment: This is all personal preference. I would personally make each assignment its own project.

Comment: As Kevin said this is about preference. There is no right solution to this. I also would use multiple projects. Voting to close because it's opinion based.

Comment: Sure, it might be opinion-based, but there should be some degree of convention here, and that is what I'm looking for.

Comment: There really isn't a convention. Do whichever seems most natural to you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the **[maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven)** build infrastructure. This has a plugin in eclipse. Especially nice is the automatic (versioned) library management ("dependency management"), and one can easily create small projects, or collect subprojects ("modules") under one umbrella project.

You then have many real small projects.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

1) Yes they should, each project should really just have one src folder. If you wanted to do them as separate projects that would also be fine.

2) To me its nicer to structure them that way as each lecture may have multiple classes.

Perhaps have a package above the subject_xxx packages.

eg. yourname.subjectone

That will allow for future expansion if you want to break out and add things that arent subjects. It will also allow forbetter integration if you add multiple projects

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here there is section on packages.

http://wiki.unixcraft.com/display/MainPage/Java+Packaging+Executable+JAR

Answer (score -1):

Make a single folder named src, and all the folder structures will be inside it as packages.

```
  My School
   |
   |----src
   |     |
   |     |---Subject_one
   |     |      |-----//.java files
   |     |
   |     |---Subject_two
   |     |      |----//.java files
   |     |
```